# How to scroll left a particular div in seleinium?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

While I'm testing one angular page, I needed to scroll a particular segment to left. I tried the following code.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(200,200)", "");
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved with selenium Mouse interaction, below code could give you a idea.

```
 WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.id("slider"));
     int width=slider.getSize().getWidth();
     Actions move = new Actions(driver);
     Action action= move.dragAndDropBy(slider, ((width*25)/100), 0).build();
     action.perform();
```

Please let me know is that what you where looking for ?